# Php how to hide elements

Tags: php, hide, element

Hello is there any possible way how to hide elements for example inputs on page with php ?

anything like with css

```
input{display:none}
```

Comment: You have to use an IF...ELSE structure to decide which HTML block will be displayed. There is no any way to hide HTML elements in server side without not sending them to client. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: you should try google before you post questions like this. Try searching for hide html element (https://www.google.com/search?q=hide+html+element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output HTML and CSS code hiding elements from your PHP.
`<h1 style=display:"<?php echo "none";>">`